# how many time a char have been repeted in a random string

Tags: c#, random, char

I have this code which is a simple game you pick how many questions and how many characters you want and the program generate a random string of characters and numbers but how do I pick one random character every question and ask the user how many time this char have been repeated for example
**how many time char A have been repeated in this string: iasfhAjfalkjA
answer = 2 times**

I don't know If I should put the whole code but I think it helps here is my code

```
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random randomgen = new Random();
            int a; string Sa; int b; string sb;
            int maxanswer = 0;
            int m = 0;
            string question;
            string sss;
            string quit = "QUIT";
            string useranswer;
            string answer ;
            int numofquestions;
            int numofquestionsleft;
            int numofcorrect = 0;
            int numoffalse = 0;

            //ASKING THE USER FOR THE MAX NUMBER OF QUESTIONS WANT TO BE ASKED
            Console.Write("Max Question : ");
            numofquestions = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            numofquestionsleft = numofquestions;
            //ASKING THE USER TO PUT A NUMBER BETWEEN 3 AND 100 THAT WILL HELP GENERATE A RANDOM string


            Console.WriteLine("enter a value between 3 and 100");
            Sa = Console.ReadLine(); a = Int32.Parse(Sa);

//here is the random generating part
      String sarffsa = "A1a2B3b4C5c6D7d8E9eFfGgHhIiKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"; 
                while (numofquestionsleft > 0 && m <= numofquestions + 1)
                {
                    int length = a;

                String random = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
                {
                    int alphapet = randomgen.Next(42);
                    random = random + sarffsa.ElementAt(alphapet);
                    
                }
                Console.WriteLine("How many time the symbol has been repeted in the follwing characters: {0}", random);

                 answer = Console.ReadLine();

                // adding the question and the user answer and the right answer to an array
                questionlist[m] = random;
                useranswer = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                useranswerlist[m] = answer;
                rightanswerslist[m] = answer;

                Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------");
                // IF USER TYPE QUIT THAT WILL SKIP THE QUESTION AND ADD IT TO WRONG ANSWERS LIST
                if (answer== quit)
                {
                    numofquestionsleft--;
                    ;
                    continue;

                }
              


                numofquestionsleft--;
                //LOOP
                m++;
            }

            while (1 < 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"TO GET THE NUMBER OF THE RIGHT ANSWERS PRESS 1
TO GET THE NUMBER OF THE WRONG ANSWERS PRESS 2
TO GET THE OPERATION WITH THE MAX NUMBERS OF RIGHT ANSWERS PRESS 3
TO GET THE OPERATION WITH THE MAX NUMBERS OF FALSE ANSWERS PRESS 4
TO VIEW ALL THE QUESTIONS AND YOUR ANSWERS AND CORRECT ANSWERS TYPE 5
TO EXIT TYPE EXIT
");
                sb = Console.ReadLine();

                b = Int32.Parse(sb);
                switch (b)
                {
                    // the number of right answers 
                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("You have = " + numofcorrect + " Right answers");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        // the number of wrong answers
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("You have = " + numoffalse + " Wrong answers");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
                        break;
                    // Making the rightoperationlist into a group in order and count to show the most frequent array used
                    case 3:
                        var result = (from operation in rightoperationlist
                                      group operation by operation into og
                                      orderby og.Count() descending
                                      select og.Key).FirstOrDefault();


                        Console.WriteLine("RIGHT ANSWER OPERATION = " + result);

                        break;
                    case 4:
                        // Making the Wrongoperationlist into a group in order and count to show the most frequent array used
                        var result02 = (from operation in wrongoperationlist
                                        group operation by operation into og
                                        orderby og.Count() descending
                                        select og.Key).FirstOrDefault();
                        Console.WriteLine("WRONG ANSWER OPERATIONS = " + result02);

                        break;
                    //showing the questions and user answer and the right answer arrays
                    case 5:
                        Console.WriteLine("QUESTIONS               ANSWERS                RIGHTANSWERS");
                        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        for (int z = 0; z < numofquestions; z++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(questionlist[z] + "                 " + useranswerlist[z] + "                   " + rightanswerslist[z]);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;

                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you were wondering why you never see a Q or a Z in your string, check your `randomgen.Next` call. Is this a homework question?

Comment: What is exactly your question? I read this "how do I pick one random character every question and ask the user how many time this char have been repeated". Do you have trouble to pick a random character? does this character needs to be included in the random string, or do you accept answers that could be zero (and will most probably be zero if your string is not long enough). Then what is the second part of your question? Do you need to determinate the actual answer?

Answer (score 1):

To pick one random character (as a string) in the generated random string:

```cs
var Symbol = random[randomgen.Next(random.Length)].ToString();
```

To get the actual answer:

```cs
var GameAnswer = random.Count(c => c.ToString() == Symbol);
```

Of course, if the random character is to be stored as a `char` instead of a `string`, it becomes even simpler because we can get rid of the two `ToString()` calls.

It becomes

```cs
var Symbol = random[randomgen.Next(random.Length)]; // Here Symbol type is char
```

To get the actual answer:

```cs
var GameAnswer = random.Count(c => c == Symbol);
```

Comment: Curious why you did it with string..

Comment: Good comment. Firstly, this is kind of a temporary answer, I'm not even sure what @safdasfasfasfa really wants, hence my comment on his question which is still not answered.

Comment: Secondly, @safdasfasfasfa is using only strings in his code, and I thought that introducing a char variable (`Symbol`)might be confusing to him. I tend to use var for variable declaration and initialisation, because in Visual Studio, the type is always available. And it makes the problem less visible. So I maybe also should not use var in this kind of context to make things clearer, which might have given me more courage to use char, and avoid the two `ToString()` calls

Comment: @CaiusJard: edited my answer to reflect your comment.